# Python script to execute external commands

Tags: python, automation, remote-access

I need to issue some commands to the currently executing program and get the output of the current (remotely) executing program into some string in the script. The problem I am currently encountering is that I don't know the output of each command which output can also vary as it can be read from user.

e.g.

1. ./my_program
2. print_output_1  [ with in *my_program* ]
3. print_output_2  [ with in *my_program* ]
4. exit  [ with in *my_program* ]

and if i run the commands manually terminal will get something like this

```
bash$ ./my_programe
my_program: print_output_1
my_program:first_line_printed_with_unknown_length
my_program: print_output_2
my_program:second_line_printed_with_unknown_length
my_program: exit
bash$
```

so i should get "first_line_printed_with_unknown_length" and "second_line_printed_with_unknown_length" in a python string like

```
execute(my_program)
str1 = execute( print_output_1 )
str2 = execute( print_output_2 )
val = execute( exit )
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, you should. If you have, what was the outcome? ..but yes, you can do this with `Python`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please tell any package name that i can look at.

Comment: I have added an answer for you. It should give you a very basic idea of how to go about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute external commands. It is best to start with much simpler commands first to get the gist of it all. Below is a dummy example:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

def main():
    process = subprocess.Popen('echo %USERNAME%', stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    username = process.communicate()[0]
    print username #prints the username of the account you're logged in as

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will grab the output from `echo %USERNAME%` and store it. Pretty simply to give you the general idea.

From the aforementioned documentation:

> Warning: Using shell=True can be a security hazard. See the warning
>   under Frequently Used Arguments for details.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with ssh (i.e. the `ssh` command), and ssh, like any shell-executable command can be wrapped in Python, so the answer is yes. Something like this could work (I did not try though):

```
import subprocess

remote_command = ['ls', '-l']
ssh_command = ['ssh', 'user@hostname.com'] + remote_command
proc = subprocess.Popen(ssh_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

# stdout now contains the output of the remote command
# stderr now contains the error stream from the remote command or from ssh
```

You can also use Paramiko which is an ssh implementation in Python, but that might be overkill if you do not need interactivity.